# Eliminate TypeScript error for the function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a task to implement a "Clear" button for select that would revert the value for the select to the default.

My code looks like following

```
      const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        onChange(e, e.target.value);
      };

      const handleClear = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        onChange(e, defaultValue);
      };

<>
          <select
            {...selectProps}
            value={value}
            ref={ref}
            disabled={isDisabled}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {wrappedChildren()}
          </select>

          {isClearable && defaultValue && (
            <>
              <IconClear
                size="small"
                Icon={Close}
                onClick={handleClear}
              />
            </>
          )}
         </>
```

For what I am getting an error

```
Type '(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<Element>) => void'.
```

Do I understand right that I need to extend the interface for onClick event for IconClear component? And how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>` is for change events on HTML `<select>` elements whereas for the click of the clear icon, the event type could be `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>`.

```js
const handleClear = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  onChange(e, defaultValue);
};
```